# Trying to use this.props.dispatch and returns that is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to delete an item from DB but when I access the function is saying `_this.props.dispatch is not a function. (In '_this.props.dispatch((0, _actions.deleteJob)(_this.props.id))', '_this.props.dispatch' is undefined)`

Here is my code where I am calling the function to delete my item. The function `onDelete()` I am calling it after user interaction.

```
class JobItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeRowKey: null,
      deleting: false
    };
  }
  onDelete = () =>   {
    this.setState({deleting: true});
    this.props.dispatch(deleteJob(this.props.id)); // HERE is the error
  }
  render() {
    const swipeSettings = {
      autoClose: true,
      onClose: (secId, rowId, direction) => {
        this.setState({ activeRowKey: null });
      },
      onOpen: (secId, rowId, direction) => {
        this.setState({ activeRowKey: this.props.id });
      },
      right: [
        { 
          onPress: () => {
            const deletingRow = this.state.activeRowKey;
            Alert.alert(
              'Alert',
              'Are you sure you want to delete?',
              [
                {text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style:'cancel'},
                {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => {
                  this.onDelete();
                  // Refresh Job List
                  this.props.parentFlatList.refreshJobList(deletingRow);
                }},
              ],
              { cancelable: true }
            )
          },
          text: 'Delete', type: 'delete'
        }
      ],
      rowId: this.props._id,
      sectionId: 1
    }
```

And here is the `deleteJob()` function where it actually delete it from DB

```
export function deleteJob(job_id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
      return axios.delete(JOB_URL(user_id, job_id), {
        headers: { authorization: token }
      }).then((response) => {
        dispatch(removeJob(job_id));
      }).catch((err) => {
        dispatch(addAlert("Couldn't delete job."));
      });
  };
}
```

JobItem

```
var renderJobs = () => {
  return this.props.jobs.map((job) => {
    return (
      <JobItem 
        parentFlatList={this}
        key={job._id} 
        title={job.title} 
        shortDescription={job.shortDescription} 
        logo={job.avatar} 
        company={job.company} 
        id={job._id}/>
    )
  })
}
var mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    jobs: state.jobs
  }
}
module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps)(JobList);
```

Any idea how shall I solve this?

Comment: Can you add the code where you connect `JobItem` to Redux?

Comment: @riwu Please see my edit

Comment: Still don't see the part with `connect` called.

Comment: you are probably missing `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: @riwu I've added now

Comment: It's connected to `JobList`. Did you connect to `JobItem`?

Comment: I have two classes in the same js first  `JobItem` and second `JobList`

Comment: Can you post the entire js file as one code block then?

Comment: @riwu I've putted the code here https://jsfiddle.net/7zhczan1/1/ because it doesn't allow me

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to pass dispatch to JobItem

```
<JobItem 
    parentFlatList={this}
    key={job._id} 
    title={job.title} 
    shortDescription={job.shortDescription} 
    logo={job.avatar} 
    company={job.company} 
    id={job._id}
    dispatch={this.props.dispatch} /* <-- this one here */
/>
```

Comment: by `renderJobs` you mean the render method in `JobList` right ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix the problem is to put JobItem inside container.
Something like this

module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps,dispatch=>({dispatch}))(JobItem);

Comment: This is actually working to delete it but it delete it only from view. If I slide down it will reappear. It doesn't delete it from DB.

Comment: This is what my server returns in terminal when I delete and after that I refresh the page `"DELETE /v1/users/5adaa55c0364d01cd9478492/jobs/5adaa5ff0364d01cd9478497 HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "Expo/2.4.7.1013849 CFNetwork/897.15 Darwin/17.5.0"` then I refresh `"GET /v1/users/5adaa55c0364d01cd9478492/jobs HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Expo/2.4.7.1013849 CFNetwork/897.15 Darwin/17.5.0"`

Comment: Please let me know how you have configured your deleteJob with redux.

Comment: In reducer or action?

Comment: I believe you have configured deleteJob as middleware, which is listening to actions and perform intended operation.

Comment: deletedJob is actually in actions and the function is in my post